# Disable GPG signature check for repo init (and/or for git)

Tags: git, repo, gpg-signature

I'm trying to setup an AOSP repository with the `repo init` command, however I get a signature checking error (I edited out all the actual names and object IDs):

```
repo: error: "git" failed with exit status 1
  cwd: /aoap/.repo/repo
  cmd: ['git', 'tag', '-v', 'v1.12.16']
  stdout:
  >> object 0123456789abcdef0123456789abcdef01234567
  >> type commit
  >> tag v1.12.16
  >> tagger Foo Bar <foobar@android.com> 0123456789 -0700
  >> 
  >> repo 1.12.16
  stderr:
  >> gpg: Signature made gio 31 feb 2022, 12:34:56 CEST
  >> gpg:                using RSA key 0123456789ABCDEF
  >> gpg: Can't check signature: No public key
fatal: cloning the git-repo repository failed, will remove '.repo/repo'
```

Is there a way to skip or disable the GPG signature check (for this `repo init`, or even globally for `git`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check first if a [global config](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-commitgpgSign) (just for the time of the repo init command) would help

```
git config --global tag.gpgSign false
git config --global commit.gpgSign false
```

If this is not working (since it is likely for *creating* tag/commit, rather than checking them), check the configuration [gpg.program](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-gpgprogram)

By replacing it with a script which always return 0, you might (again just for the `repo init`) bypass any gpg check

```
git config --global gpg.program myGpg
```

With `myGpg` an executable bash script on the $PATH% with

```
#!/bin/bash
exit 0
```

Comment: Unfortunately neither of these worked. Apparently the script is not being invoked.

Comment: @lornova My second config was incorrect. Did you try `gpg.program`? I have edited the answer.

Comment: yes using `gpg.program` solved the gpg issue, thanks